# How to assign complex numbers to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, complex-numbers

I am trying to assign complex numbers to an initialized NumPy arrays in the following way
`MG = np.zeros((len(Mx), len(My), len(Mz)), dtype=np.complex)`, shape of MG is
`print(MG.shape) = (97, 97, 121)`.

I have the data as-
`print(data.shape) = (1, 192, 192, 240)`  and I take the fft of the data as- `CG=np.fft.rfftn(data) print(CG.shape) = (1, 192, 192, 121)`.
The content of CG is also complex number- `print(CG[0, 1, 1, 1]) = (-323.8670860547882-348.25820462723163j)`.

I am trying to assign this MG as-

```
for i in range(len(Mxc)):
    for j in range(len(Myc)):
        for k in range(len(Mzc)):
            MM = Mxc[i,j,k]**2 + Myc[i,j,k]**2 + Mzc[i,j,k]**2
            if MM < 0.0005:
                MG[i,j,k] = CG[i,j,k]/MM
```

where `Mxc,Myc,Mzc = np.meshgrid(Mx,My,Mz)`,
with Mx,My, and Mz are numpy arrays of floats.

However, I am getting the following error-

```
<ipython-input-13-c0f2a935a1dd> in <module>
---> 14                 MG[i,j,k] = CG[i,j,k]/MM
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Can anyone please help me with it?

Comment: That's not appending, that's just assignment.  Append means adding a new value, as with a list append.  For arrays we have to use some sort of `concatenate`.  You aren't doing that.

Comment: Check the `shape` of all elements in the problem line.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to "assign".

Comment: @hpaulj, could you please show me how to concatenate, I am not sure I understood what you meant here? I think my error is coming from wrong indexing.

Comment: CG is a 4-D array, but you try to index it as `CG[i,j,k]`. That's the problem.

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys, usually I see a `sequence` error for such a case, but apparently with complex dtype the error message is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Han-KwangNienhuys points out `CG` has more dimensions than `MG`.

Normally I'd expect such an assignment to produce `sequence error`:

```
In [270]: x = np.ones((3,2)); y = np.zeros((2,3,2))                             
In [271]: x[0,0] = y[0,0]                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-271-c61c21c08d16> in <module>
----> 1 x[0,0] = y[0,0]

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

But with complex dtype, the error message is different, what you got:

```
In [272]: x = np.ones((3,2),complex); y = np.zeros((2,3,2),complex)             
In [273]: x[0,0] = y[0,0]                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-273-c61c21c08d16> in <module>
----> 1 x[0,0] = y[0,0]

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand the problem now. I can easily reshape the 4D array to 3D array, but, I am not sure if that would still keep the indexing I want, meaning, how to reshape the 4D CG array to 3D array such a way that MG[i,j,k] = CG[i,j,k].